# Attribute values used inside ng-messages is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular js,I developed an Employee webpage where I have to provide list of references..The following code is not working

```js
<form name="referForm" data-ng-submit="upsertReferences(this)" method="post">
            <div class="text-label" >
                <input type="text" id="r_fullname_{{index}}" ng-minlength="4"
                       data-ng-attr-class="{ 'error': (referForm.r_fullname_{{index}}.$dirty) && (referForm.r_fullname_{{index}}.$invalid) }"
                       name="r_fullname_{{index}}" data-ng-attr-model="reference.fullname" data-ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]+$/"  required="required"
                       data-ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'submit' }"/>
                <label for="r_fullname_{{index}}">Full Name</label>
            </div>
            <div data-ng-message-exp="referForm.r_fullname_{{index}}.$error" data-ng-show="referForm.r_fullname_{{index}}.$touched">
                <div class="error-message" data-ng-messages="required">Please enter your name.</div>
                <div class="error-message" data-ng-show="(referForm.r_fullname_{{index}}.$error.minlength )&&!(referForm.r_fullname_{{index}}.$error.pattern)">Your field is too short</div>
                <div class="error-message" data-ng-show="referForm.r_fullname_{{index}}.$error.pattern" >Enter Aplhabets Only</div>--!>

            </div>
</form>
```

since there is an error using {{index}} in ng-messages,ng-show,ng-hide, I replaced them with this.$eval(index)['$error'] but still validations are not working.So I have moved out of ng-messages and started using ng-if

```js
<div data-ng-if="error_one" data-ng-attr-value="referForm.r_fullname_{{index}}.$error">
                <div class="error-message" data-ng-messages="required">Please enter your name.</div>
                <div class="error-message" data-ng-if="length_error" data-ng-attr-value="(referForm.r_fullname_{{index}}.$error.minlength )&&!(referForm.r_fullname_{{index}}.$error.pattern)">Your field is too short</div>
                <div class="error-message" data-ng-if="number_error" data-ng-attr-value="referForm.r_fullname_{{index}}.$error.pattern" >Enter Aplhabets Only</div>
            </div>
```

This is also not working ..Any help is greatly appreciated..I am struggling  from hours to get it done ,Thanks in advance